# Unable to launch the services.msc on windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, services

I am currently unable to launch the services.msc panel from my windows 10 computer.

Here is the complete french message I have from the window :

> La console MMC ne peut pas créer ce composant logiciel enfichable en
> raison des stratégies utilisateur en vigueur. Nom : Services CLSID :
> {58221C66-EA27-11CF-ADCF-00AA00A80033}
>
> Translation:
> The MMC can not create this snap-in because of user policies that are enforced

Following [this](https://support.microsoft.com/fr-fr/help/914231/when-i-tried-to-open-device-manager-or-the-computer-management-window) documentation and [this](https://www.commentcamarche.net/forum/affich-2512243-mmc) one, I tried without success this steps

1. `Regsvr32 Msxml.dll`=> module not found
2. `Regsvr32 Msxml2.dll`=> module not found
3. `Regsvr32 Msxml3.dll`=> success
4. Installation of "Microsoft XML Parser (MSXML) 3.0 Service Pack 4 (SP4)"
5. `SFC /scannow`

Unfortunately, even with a reboot I still can't open services.msc

Running the following command (`Get-Acl -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MMC\SnapIns\{58221C66-EA27-11CF-ADCF-00AA00A80033}"| Format-List *`) gives me this output :

```
PSPath                  : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MMC\SnapIns\{58221C66-EA27-11CF-ADCF-00AA00A80033}
PSParentPath            : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MMC\SnapIns
PSChildName             : {58221C66-EA27-11CF-ADCF-00AA00A80033}
PSDrive                 : HKLM
PSProvider              : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry
CentralAccessPolicyId   : 
CentralAccessPolicyName : 
Path                    : Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MMC\SnapIns\{58221C66-EA27-11CF-ADCF-00AA00A80033}
Owner                   : AUTORITE NT\Système
Group                   : AUTORITE NT\Système
Access                  : {System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule, System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule, System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule, 
                          System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule...}
Sddl                    : O:SYG:SYD:AI(A;CIID;KR;;;BU)(A;CIID;KA;;;BA)(A;CIID;KA;;;SY)(A;CIIOID;KA;;;CO)(A;CIID;KR;;;AC)(A;CIID;KR;;;S-1-15-3-1024-1065365936-1281604716-3511738428-1654721687
                          -432734479-3232135806-4053264122-3456934681)
AccessToString          : BUILTIN\Utilisateurs Allow  ReadKey
                          BUILTIN\Administrateurs Allow  FullControl
                          AUTORITE NT\Système Allow  FullControl
                          CREATEUR PROPRIETAIRE Allow  FullControl
                          AUTORITÉ DE PACKAGE D’APPLICATION\TOUS LES PACKAGES D’APPLICATION Allow  ReadKey
                          S-1-15-3-1024-1065365936-1281604716-3511738428-1654721687-432734479-3232135806-4053264122-3456934681 Allow  ReadKey
AuditToString           : 
AccessRightType         : System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryRights
AccessRuleType          : System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule
AuditRuleType           : System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAuditRule
AreAccessRulesProtected : False
AreAuditRulesProtected  : False
AreAccessRulesCanonical : True
AreAuditRulesCanonical  : True
```

Comment: What happens when you try to access it in control panel?

Comment: @Moab I have the same message launching it throught cmd

Comment: All I can suggest is to run this command: SFC/ scannow

Comment: @Moab unfortunately no corrupted file detected :(

Comment: If you do not find a solution: Cave and Pave, back up your data and do a Reset....https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026528/windows-10-reset-or-reinstall

Comment: Check permissions to related registry key using `regedit.exe` tool (or from elevated Powershell: `Get-Acl -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MMC\SnapIns\{58221C66-EA27-11CF-ADCF-00AA00A80033}"`)

Comment: @JosefZ I edited the question to add the powershell response

Comment: Is your computer part of a workgroup or a domain?

Comment: @JosefZ yes it is

Comment: A workgroup **or** a domain (_tertium non datur_, I know:)) So, **which one**?

Comment: @JosefZ a domain

Comment: Then ask your domain admin…

Answer (score 0):

The error message in English probably looks more like this:

```
MMC could not create the snap-in, the snap-in might not have been installed correctly.
Name: Services
CLSID:{58221C66-EA27-11CF-ADCF-00AA00A8033}
```

This snap-in module, Services, is defined in the registry at key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MMC\SnapIns\{58221C66-EA27-11CF-ADCF-00AA00A80033}`.

The handler defined there is `filemgmt.dll`, which is probably corrupt or missing.

Try first running an elevated Command Prompt and entering the following command:

```
regsvr32 filemgmt.dll
```

My guess is that you will receive an error message, but if not, then try running
Services again.

If this does not work, run
[sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
as described in the link to see if Windows is corrupted.

Comment: `regsvr32 filemgmt.dll` succeded. I reboot and try again `services.msc`

Comment: Nothing changed :(

Comment: Continue then with `sfc /scannow`.

Comment: The OP's translation is probably right: _The MMC console cannot create this snap-in because of the current user policies._ (Google Translate from _detected_ French).